# Using a calculated value in a static function

Tags: ios, swift

I have a static function that I need to use a calculated value in. The function is laid out thus:

```
fileprivate static func getToken() {
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: Constant.AuthRequestURL.Values.IDTokenURL)!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
        request.addValue(getUserAgent(), forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
        request.addValue(Constant.AuthRequestHeader.Values.ContentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
}
```

Currently I cannot run this bit of code because it can't access `getUserAgent()` which I've attempted to define at the class level above with this block:

```
func getUserAgent() -> String {
       let app = "default"
       let version = Bundle.main.infoDictionary["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String
       let bundleId = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleIdentifier"] as? String
       let build = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String
       let iOS = UIDevice.current.systemVersion
       userAgent = "\(app)/\(version ?? "6.2.1")) (\(bundleId ?? "default"); build:\(build ?? "1014"); x86_64; iOS \(iOS); scale:2.0)"
       return userAgent
       }
```

I'm guessing there is something wrong with how I am defining the function because I'm not instantiating an object with this as a member? How can I give my static function access to the function to generate the UserAgent string at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read up on static methods vs. instance methods

Instance methods require there to be an instance of the class already initialized, and you call these methods from the instance of the class.

Static methods are not attached to a specific instance of the class and can be called anywhere. For that reason they can't access methods that are specific to an instance of the class because the static method doesn't have access to an instance of the class.

eg:

```
class Thing() {

    var a = 0

    func doThing() {
        // is called from an instance of Thing meaning it can access `a`
        a = 1
        print(a)  // prints 1
    }

    static func doOtherThing() {
        // can be called from anywhere so there is no guarentee `a` exists.
        // in fact it's guarenteed that from the context of this method `a` does not exist

        // but we could make an instance of thing
        let thing = Thing()

        print(thing.a) // prints 0
        thing.doThing() // prints 1
        print(thing.a) // prints 1

        // and we could have a different thing
        let thingTwo = Thing()
        print(thing.a != thingTwo.a) // True since its 1 != 0
    }
}
```

As such you have a few options:

1 - Make your static method not static so when it is called it will have an instance of the class to call the non-static method from.

2 - Make your non-static method static so it can be called from the other static method without needing an instance of the class.

3 - Make an instance of the class in the static method and call the non-static method from that instance of the class.

Hope I explained that well enough to make sense